# Risk of electrocution under electric poles on a big raining day

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

Like the downpour creates a path between the high voltage wires and you or your car parked underneath them, would the current passes through you to the ground when you are walking close to electric poles or when you touch your parked car door?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very unlikely since the the water from rain comes in single droplets and not long connected streams of water.

However if it did rain the way you describe and for an instant there is a stream of water going from the power lines to you or your car, then you could get electrocuted. The high voltage in power lines have the actual physical ground as the "earth" and if shorted in this manner, current will flow from the lines to the ground. If you or your car (that you are touching) form part of this circuit then you can get electrocuted.

But as stated above, the possibility of this occurring is probably zero due to the form of rain drops, and in fact I've never heard of such a thing happening.

Comment: Thank you! So its is luck that rains are not ever heavy enough for the droplets to form a connected (or close to connected) stream of water?

Comment: Would be interesting to prove in another physics stack exchange question with formula that rain droplets are not connected :D

Comment: It would be interesting.

Comment: @user1589188 If the rain were *that* dense, you'd drown and be swept away in the flood. ;)